# Tirar a contagem de um ranking

Tags: php, sql, tabela-html, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou com um sistema de ranking de filmes no meu site e preciso que ele **NÃO** mostre a quantidade de usuários que recomendaram tal filme, aqui está meu código :

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT filmes, count(filmes) FROM filmes_rec 
          GROUP by filmes
          ORDER by count(filmes) DESC LIMIT 10";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    foreach($row as $field => $value) {
        echo '<hr class="break"><tr><p class="title">' . htmlspecialchars($value) . '</p></tr>';
    }
}
```

[image: Esse é o ranking, preciso tirar esses números daí]

Comment: Para resolver isso, é só colocar índice no value e mostrar apenas os values com os índices que deseja. no caso, `$field` é seu índice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Opção 1:**

Irei desconsiderar que você faz uso do resultado de sua query após o o loop então altere ela para:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT filmes FROM filmes_rec 
          GROUP by filmes
          ORDER by count(filmes) DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Assim só vai apresentar os nomes dos filmes.

**Opção 2:**

Altere este trecho de código:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    foreach($row as $field => $value) {
        if ($field != 'filmes') continue;
        echo '<hr class="break"><tr><p class="title">' . htmlspecialchars($value) . '</p></tr>';
    }
}
```

**Obs:** *Use uma ou outra opção, não é necessário as duas.*

Comment: Continue pode ficar confuso na hora de debugar. Eu trocaria por `if($field == 'filmes') echo '...'`.

Comment: Só poderei testar o código de noite,  mas você poderia me explicar o porque isso tiraria os números? Gostaria de aprender isso.

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi a pergunta eu faria de outra forma: usaria o `assoc()` para associar as colunas e imprimiria somente a coluna com o nome dos filmes, o sql já fará a ordenação:

**PHP**

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT filmes, count(filmes) FROM filmes_rec 
      GROUP by filmes
      ORDER by count(filmes) DESC LIMIT 10";

$result = $link->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows() >0){

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<hr class="break"><tr><p class="title">' .$row['filmes']. '</p></tr>';
  }

}else{
 echo '<p>Sem Resultados</p>';
}
```